# When posting from a html form it can find my action file

Tags: php, html

Basically I have a html form where the

```
action="newlist.php"
```

and it is in the same directory as the php file and whenever I submit it I get the error,

```
Not Found

The requested URL /~u1418925/cs139/â€˜newlist.phpâ€™ was not found on this server.
```

what could be causing this, the permissions on all my php files are all chmod a+rx *.php . Thanks in advance.

**Sorry I had single quotations around the file but now I have changed it do double it seems to find the file, however the file is not inserting these values into the data base, all the code is below**

Form code:

```
<form action="newlist.php" method="POST">
    List Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name='list_name'><br><br>
    List Importance(0-5):<br>
    <input type="text" name=‘list_importance’><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create List">
</form>
```

newlist.php Code:

```
<?php
   require 'database.php';
   $listname = $_POST["list_name"];
   $listimportance = $_POST["list_importance"];

   $db = new Database();
   $db->exec("INSERT INTO lists VALUES(NULL, 1, $listname, NA, $listimportance, 0);");

?>
```

Schema.sql code:

```
DROP TABLE users;
CREATE TABLE users(id integer primary key, username varchar(30), password varchar(30), email varchar(50), receive_email blob, gender varchar(6));

DROP TABLE lists;
CREATE TABLE lists(id integer primary key, user_id integer, name varchar(50), creation_date datetime, importance integer, completed blob);

DROP TABLE list_item;
CREATE TABLE list_item(id integer primary key, list_id integer, name varchar(50), creation_date datetime, completed blob);
```

database.php code:

```
<?php
class Database {

        private $database;

        function __construct() {
                $this->database = $this->getConnection();
        }

        function __destruct() {
                $this->database->close();
        }

        function exec($query) {
                $this->database->exec($query);
        }

        function query($query) {
                $result = $this->database->query($query);
                return $result;
        }

        function querySingle($query) {
                $result = $this->database->querySingle($query,true);
                return $result;
        }

        function prepare($query) {
                return $this->database->prepare($query);
        }
        function escapeString($string) {
                return $this->database->escapeString($string);
        }

        private function getConnection() {
                $conn = new SQLite3('todo.db');
                return $conn;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full code of your form.

Comment: If its `action"newlist.php"` its wrong. It needs to be `action="newlist.php"`…

Comment: You have strange quote marks around the field name `name=‘list_importance’>` fix them to normal quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what do you try achieve do mus t be at least:

```
$created_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$db->exec("INSERT INTO lists 
VALUES(
   NULL,
   1,".
   SQLite3::escapeString ($listname).",
   $created_date ,
   $listimportance,".
   SQLite3::escapeString ('0')."
 );
");
```

the first step you should do, just replace all variables in this query to any values, and try to get result

Answer (score 0):

As @Darren suggested, it must be action="target.php"
There's a typo.